# jquery shifting of popup when content increases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div which is dynamic and getting the increments in the css dynamically from jquery to fit the contents if they are larger.

now the problem is that there is one popup associated with the same div.

if content increase that popup's comes down, I don't know how to solve this issue . please help.

HTML

```
< div id='main_div' >

< div id='myid' >some info< /div >

< div id='popup' >< /div >

< /div >


< input type='button' id='incre' >
```

jQuery:

```
$("#incre").click(function()
    {

$("#myid").html(" some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more  some more ");

    });
```

Thanks advance
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have increased the height of 'main_div' manually. and inserted the popup under that. and that worked.

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Set max height for this div. When content increases beyond this max height, use scrollbar to scroll contents.

```
div{
    max-height:300px;
    height:auto !important;          // for ie as it does not support max-height
    height:300px;                    // for ie as it does not support max-height
    overflow:auto;
    width:auto
}
```

Comment: when content is big it's height is getting the increments from database so that's why there is no reason to give max-height.

Comment: Thanks Chinmayee, I got the solution from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using position absolute on the popup? Then the popup will not be affected by the height of the content div as it will be taken out of the flow of the document

Comment: and you are setting the left: and top: properties?